# how to add files to SVN

Tags: svn, commit, subversion-edge

im trying to add a word document to my svn repository, however im confused on how to, im doing it through terminal

```
 A    wc4/code
 A    wc4/code/branches
  A    wc4/code/prototype_demo
 A    wc4/code/tags
 A    wc4/code/trunk
 A    wc4/docs
 A    wc4/docs/0_diaries
 A    wc4/docs/1_plan
A    wc4/docs/2_interim_report
```

these are the files and i've done 
"cd wc4/docs/2_interim_report"
then "svn mkdir interim"
which made another sub file interim

how do i add my word document inside it because when i do

"svn add /desktop/interim report" which is where the file is saved it is giving me error

```
  W150002: '/Users/char/wc4/docs/2_interim_report/interim' 
  is already under version control
  svn: warning: W155010: 
 '/Users/char/wc4/docs/2_interim_report/report.doc' not found
 svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets don't exist
svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets are already versioned
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to:

```
svn add wc4/docs/2_interm_report/interm/report.doc
svn commit wc4/docs
```

---

Adding files is fairly simple. If I want to add `dir1/file1` to my repository and upload to the server I would:

```
svn add dir1/file1
svn commit dir1/file1
```

But what is `dir1` doesn't exist already? In that case I'd make the directory (doesn't need to be done in SVN) and then make the file like normal. Then simply:

```
svn add dir1
svn commit dir1
```

This will add `dir1` and all child directories/files to the svn repository, ready to be committed.

---

When the output of `svn status` shows an `A` before your filename, it means you have "added" that file/directory to your working copy and it is ready to be sent to the server.  You need to follow that up with an `svn commit` to send it to the server.

---

`svn mkdir` is mostly useful if you want to create a directory on a repository directly without checking out a working copy first. For example, I'd use `svn mkdir http://example.com/svn/repo/trunk` to make a directory named `trunk` in a remote repository before checking it out to add fresh content.

Comment: thank you but when trying to add my interim report from desktop its still showing me the same error  im using svn add desktop/interim report. Ive used your method svn add wc4/docs/2_interm_report/interm/report.doc
svn commit wc4/docs   aswell but i get the same error